# Can Craft be used with conjunction with other framework (Laravel)?

Tags: craft-features

Can Craft be used with conjunction with other framework (Laravel) or its a standalone solution?

Comment: This is a very broad question – it'd be helpful if you could add a specific example (or two), describing what you hope to achieve by pairing Craft and Laravel.

Comment: Relevant: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/14849/existing-website-written-in-php-zend-framework, https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/17359/researching-craft-cms-but-we-are-a-net-shop?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

**Craft is frequently used in conjunction with other applications/frameworks. *How* one would use Craft in coordination with a Laravel application, and whether that would be a good idea, depends on the specific use case.**

Most frequently, Craft is used to serve a content [API](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ElementAPI) that other applications can consume. Additionally, it's common to se Laravel apps used [as an intermediary](http://zaengle.com/blog/laravel-as-an-intermediary) to broker integrations between the CMS and external services.

In any case, there's no specific technical limitation that would prevent Craft and Laravel from being used in conjunction with each other.