# Researching Craft CMS but we are a .NET Shop

Tags: plugin-development, craft-features

I am involved with researching various CMS solutions and Craft CMS is one of the options for our organization as an Enterprise soluton, so not just for development use cases. When it comes to development we are mostly a Microsoft shop when it comes to the front-end so my question is, and I apologize for my ignorance on this, can I have an ASP.NET web application pull content from Craft? From what I can tell it looks like Twig is the development language, which again as I understand it is a language that generates PHP. We are not a PHP shop by any means so just wondering if there is some sort of plug-in or API that I could make calls to from an ASP.NET web application to pull out content from Craft. Is there anyone doing anything like this?

Again, I apologize for my ignorance but just trying to clear up some of the high level questions being brought up.

Thanks!

Comment: If you have any additional sales-y questions feel free to email us directly at hello@craftcms.com :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Craft can definitely work as a "headless" CMS that you can put whatever want in front of. The go-to solution for such setups is the first-party [Element API plugin](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ElementAPI).

For more info, [Mijingo just released a free lesson on Element API](https://craftcms.com/news/mijingo-element-api-lesson) and using Craft as a headless CMS.

It's also worth mentioning that [Craft 3](https://craftcms.com/3) (currently in dev preview; public beta ETA early 2017) is expected to add a RESTful API implementation to Craft core (either on release or after).

Comment: Thank you! Exactly the type of answer that I was looking for. I did discover a few other posts related to my question and Element API was mentioned so I will dig into that a bit. Very much appreciate the quick response!